# Sprite not being destroyed after being walked on (Phaser 2.4.6)

Tags: phaser

I've been developing a game for not long in the Phaser framework so I may be a little nooby so be warned.
I have a timer that runs whenever an update is called and it would set the sprite I walked on to a tanish-brown and then destroy it after half a second (500), give me one point and close the loop:

```
//This is where it calls the collision handler in the update() function. First line of it too.:
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, layer, testgame.prototype.collisionHandler, null, this);
//move player and stuff
//This is where the timer starts in the update() function
var st = game.time.create(false);
var stc = 0;
obj2.frame = 4;
st.loop(Phaser.Timer.SECOND / 8, function() {
  obj2.destroy();
  setScore(score += 1);
  st.stop();
  return;
}, this);
st.start();
```

But it would just give me a point and (not)close the loop.
I'm using arcade physics and each sprite is 32x32 while the player is 64x64.
I'm also using tilemaps, not just creating the level from code.
Thanks in advance.